# x11vnc under Ubuntu 16.10 - wrong keyboard mapping when accessing from Windows 7

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, vnc, 16.10

sorry, still quite a new-be with Ubuntu and thus may not see the obvious.

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS as well as 16.10 from scratch on a small Intel machine with a German keyboard attached. The system language is set to English, but the keyboard to standard German. When working on the system directly all is normal.

I have installed `x11vnc` as server on the box and access it from a Windows 7 notebook with a standard German keyboard using VNC Viewer 5.3.2.

The access generally works, but I noticed that some special characters are not being submitted correctly. The main problems I have are with **@** and **|**.

I have tried setting special options on the server side such as `-xkb`, `-remap DEAD`,
`-add_keysyms`, `-noadd_keysyms`, but none is the solution. One of them - forgot which after all changes - gave me the wanted characters, but suddenly I could not get the **!** anymore.

Edit: Just tested other VNC clients under Windows (VNC Viewer 6.0.0, TightVNC Viewer 2.8.5) with the same results. Must be an issue between Windows and Ubuntu as such.

What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Under 14.04 I succeeded by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and setting it to '105 key (intl)' and 'German' (which meant accepting the preselected defaults). Can you try if that works under Ubuntu 16, too?

Comment: Seems to be neccessary after every reboot...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the exact same problem for my Ubuntu 16.04LTS server that I connect to via VNC by using `setxkbmap xx`. (Adjust xx to your language. So in your case 'de')

This, however resets on reboot so you need to go to System > Preferences > Startup Applications and add a new startup programm. You can choose whatever you like for name and comment. In the command section type in `setxkbmap xx` (again replace xx with your language code).

The command is now executed at startup and will set your keylayout.